# Hardcode a specific day in data time while pulling the data - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Actually I have different date in SQL table when I pull those via SQL query, day of datetime field should have fixed day.

**Example:** (DD-MM-YYYY) day should be "7" > (7-MM-YYYY)

- **10**-08-2007 > **07**-08-2007
- **27**-12-2013 > **07**-12-2013
- **01**-03-2017 > **07**-03-2017

Can someone help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share the efforts you made so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the difference between 7 and the day of the original date and add that to the original date:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DAY(OriginalDate), OriginalDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEFROMPARTS: *Updated ONLY works from 2012 - OP has tagged SQL-Server 2008*

```
select DATEFROMPARTS ( year('10-08-2007'), month('10-08-2007'), 7 )
```

Comment: OP has tagged SQL Server 2008 - `DATEFROMPARTS` wasn't added until 2012.

Comment: @Bridge Thanks for that- I didn't see the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEPART` to take out the month and year parts. Cast those into varchar and concatenate with `07`.

**Query**

```
select '07-' + 
cast(DATEPART(mm, [date_column]) as varchar(2)) + '-' + 
cast(DATEPART(yyyy, [date_column]) as varchar(4))
from your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your field is of datetime datatype and your fixed day is of integer type.

select datetimecolumn+(yourparamfixedday-datepart(dd,datetimecolumn))

Comment: What happens if the date is the same as the month or year?

Comment: @cloudsafe date is same as the year? I'm not getting you.

Comment: if the day of month being replaced is the same as the month i.e 08/08/2008

Comment: agreed. Was careless about that replace statement. will edit that with a work around now. Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You might have to change the day number example

```
DECLARE @dayNum char(2)
SELECT @dayNum = '07'
select @dayNum + Right(convert(char(10),getdate(),105),8)
```

If that is not the case You could do this

```
select '07'+ Right(convert(char(10),'10-08-2007',105),8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this way:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)+'25',112);
```

`CONVERT` with format `112` will return the date as *unseparated ISO* (today we would get `20170407`). Convert this to `VARCHAR(6)` will implicitly cut away the day's part (`201704`).

Now we add a day and use again `CONVERT` with `112`, but now with `DATE` as target type.

One thing to keep in mind: The day you add must be *two-digit*. You can achieve this with

```
DECLARE @int INT=7;
SELECT REPLACE(STR(@int,2),' ','0');
```